# Vue is changing collection's order

Tags: laravel, sorting, collections, vuejs2, laravel-5.6

I have a collection which I am sorting using and `sortByDesc('created_at')`. When I `dd()` it before returning to my view, it changes the order.

However, as soon as I pass it to my vue component, it changes the order back.

Why is this happening? Is there a way of solving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I keep forgetting about this all the fonking time, but it's usually because the collection-sorting methods retain their keys. Quoting the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortby):

> The `sortBy` method sorts the collection by the given key. The sorted collection keeps the original array keys, so in this example we'll use the `values` method to reset the keys to consecutively numbered indexes:

Comment: Wow. It actually worked! Thanks a lot! Instead of returning `$collection->sortByDesc('created_at')`, I returned `$collection->sortByDesc('created_at')->values()` and it worked!